# Return value of yesterday in an xts object in R

Tags: r, xts

This is the tail of an xts object:

```
           SPY.Close    mavg     dn.1     up.1
2011-02-16    133.85 132.446 128.8502 130.9545
2011-02-17    134.25 132.793 129.0212 131.2241
2011-02-18    134.53 133.131 129.2198 131.5016
2011-02-22    131.83 133.117 129.4104 131.6236
2011-02-23    131.02 132.962 129.5961 131.7072
2011-02-24    130.93 132.828 129.7575 131.7792
```

Given a simple nested ifelse() function passed across each day:

```
signal <- ifelse(t$mavg > t$up.1, 1, ifelse(t$mavg < t$dn.1, -1, 99))
```

The value from this rule can be added to the object:

```
t$signal = signal
```

Yielding the new object (I've taken a section for illustration):

```
           SPY.Close    mavg      dn.1      up.1 signal
2010-11-18    119.96 120.713 118.17955 119.99845      1
2010-11-19    120.29 120.470 118.33112 120.09688      1
2010-11-22    120.19 120.240 118.47911 120.18489      1
2010-11-23    118.45 119.924 118.55112 120.20888     99
2010-11-24    120.20 119.734 118.63565 120.27635     99
```

How can I re-write the nested ifelse() statement so that each time it evaluates to 99, the value from the previous day is returned instead?

NOTE: if the nested ifelse() statement cannot be written as specified due to a chicken/egg paradox, then a separate statement to turn the 99 into 1 will suffice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You drop the 99 convention and use real NA's. Then you should make the acquaintance of zoo::na.locf, which reads "for NA's , last observation carry forward".

```
M <- read.table(textConnection(" SPY.Close    mavg      dn.1      up.1
2010-11-18    119.96 120.713 118.17955 119.99845   
2010-11-19    120.29 120.470 118.33112 120.09688   
2010-11-22    120.19 120.240 118.47911 120.18489   
2010-11-23    118.45 119.924 118.55112 120.20888   
2010-11-24    120.20 119.734 118.63565 120.27635   
") )
M <- cbind(M, signal = ifelse(M$mavg > M$up.1, 1, ifelse(M$mavg < M$dn.1, -1, NA)) )
M$signal <- na.locf(M$signal)
```

Comment: Holy Smokes that works! I knew na.locf() got rid of NAs but missed the point that it carries forward last observation. Nice to avoid another control flow statement when one is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Which value from the previous day do you want? If you want `signal` from the previous day, you can't access yesterday's value before `ifelse` finishes producing it. Try this instead:

```
tick$lagsignal <- c(NA, head(tick$signal, -1))
tick$newsignal <- ifelse(tick$signal == 99, tick$lagsignal, tick$signal)
```

Comment: tick$lagsignal <- c(NA, head(tick$signal, -1) needs an extra ) at the end.

Comment: this seems cleaner than a for loop I'm hacking, but if you have two or more consecutive tick$signal == 99, it doesn't work because the tick$lagsignal becomes a 99.